# Are Differential Line Drivers same as FDA or similair as Balun ? How we use them differently?

Tags: differential-amplifier

I'm trying to understand the difference between differential line drivers, FDA and baluns. I know that FDA and Blaun both can be used to driver ADCs and baluns are usually AC coupled and adding less noise. But I don't know much about differential line drivers for example [SN65LVDS1](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn65lvds1.pdf?HQS=dis-mous-null-mousermode-dsf-pf-null-wwe&ts=1700558190654&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.mouser.fr%252F) from TI. They are LVDS drivers but in terms of impedance, speed (freq.), etc, it seems they also can be used in RF applications... so what's the difference between them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LVDS is a digital signaling standard; it can only transmit two states.

Fully Differential Amplifiers are analog, able to transmit a continuum output voltage.

Baluns perform no amplification or buffering/isolation, being passive devices.  They only serve for impedance matching and common/differential mode conversion.